# Logstash date is not working with HH:mm:ss.SSS but working with HH:mm:ss,SSS

Tags: logstash

when i check the elasticsearch output it seems not correct with timestamp it is displaying

For HH:mm:ss.SSS (not working correctly) -> apache.log

```
"message" : "[DEBUG] 2020-12-05 12:26:18.254...
"@timestamp" : "2021-01-11T03:31:10.314Z",
```

For HH:mm:ss,SSS (working correctly) -> eai_new.log

```
"timestamp" : "2020-11-23 06:05:05,297",
"message" : "2020-11-23 06:05:05,297
"@timestamp" : "2020-11-22T22:05:05.297Z"
```

Besides that what the difference between timestamp and @timestamp?

Below is my  logstash code

```
filter {

  if [name_of_log] in ["apache"] {
    grok {
      match => { "message" => "\[%{LOGLEVEL:level}\] %{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp} %{GREEDYDATA:msg}" }
    }

    date {
      match => [ "timestamp" , "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS" ]
    }
  } else {
    grok {
      match => { "message" => "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp} %{LOGLEVEL:level} %{GREEDYDATA:msg}" }
    }
    date {
      match => [ "timestamp" , "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS" ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The date filter in logstash have a targeted field where it put the value that just will be parsed. This name of the default field is *@timestamp*.

So when data parsing is ok, the result of the parsing process is saved in the field *@timestamp*.
You have more details [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-date.html#plugins-filters-date-target) about the date filter of logstash.

If the parsing operation doesn't work, the @timestamp is put by elsaticsearch himself and the value corresponding of the date of insertion into elasticsearch side. This is the default behaviour if you haven't set a specific configuration (for mapping) in your elasticsearch example.

The *timestamp* field is set during your grok operation. In your code, this set the *timestamp* field **{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp}** in this part of logstash filter configuration:

```
grok {
  match => { "message" => "\[%{LOGLEVEL:level}\] %{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp} %{GREEDYDATA:msg}" }
}
```